# Updating cache "bust" variable programatically in require.js

Tags: requirejs

I am trying to update the bust variable in require.js so the browser is forced to re-fetch instead of loading resources from cache. I found here that several people have asked similar question.  I am trying to try with a simple piece of code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery+RequireJS Sample Page</title>
    <!-- This is a special version of jQuery with RequireJS built-in -->

    <script>
    var require = {
        urlArgs : "bust="+getRandom()
    };
    </script>
    <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require-jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
    function getRandom() {
    var buildNumber;
        $.get("/resource/buildNumber", function(data) {
            buildNumber = data;
        });
        return buildNumber;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="heading">jQuery+RequireJS Sample Page</h1>
    <p>Look at source or inspect the DOM to see how it works.</p>
</body>
```

I am trying to get the value of my build number from a properties file on the server. But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getRandom is not defined
```

So I tried this:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require-jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    var require = {
        urlArgs : "bust="+getRandom()
    };
    function getRandom() {
        var buildNumber;
        $.get("/resource/buildNumber", function(data) {
            buildNumber = data;
        });
        return buildNumber;
    }
    </script>
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'require' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

It looks like the bust variable has to be set even before require-jquery.js is declared but how do I access server side APIs without access to jquery libraries? I want to update the bust variable for every build.

Any pointers in the right directions would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: From the RequireJS site "Also, you can define the config object as the global variable require _before_ require.js is loaded, and have the values applied automatically." You're effectively overwriting the require object. Swap your script to underneath, see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I do not understand what you are saying. I looked at the documentation where you pulled the comment from. It looks like that's what I am trying to do. Did I miss anything?

Comment: You're including the require.js lib before your config code, therefore overwriting the global require var with your config. The docs explicitly state that it needs to go before the script if you use this method. Otherwise require.config() will work better.